# Why does chrome driver chrash in ubuntu WSL?

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Trying to get a simple selenium script working

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
print("options assigned")
path   = '/usr/bin/chromedriver'
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path, options=chrome_options)
```

I get this error:

```
python testscript.py
/home/guc3xq/anaconda3/envs/sas/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/__init__.py:109: RequestsDependencyWarning: urllib3 (1.26.15) or chardet (5.1.0)/charset_normalizer (2.0.12) doesn't match a supported version!
  warnings.warn(
options assigned
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/guc3xq/dev/chromedriverdev/testscript.py", line 14, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path, options=chrome_options)
  File "/home/guc3xq/anaconda3/envs/sas/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 76, in __init__
    RemoteWebDriver.__init__(
  File "/home/guc3xq/anaconda3/envs/sas/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/home/guc3xq/anaconda3/envs/sas/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/home/guc3xq/anaconda3/envs/sas/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/guc3xq/anaconda3/envs/sas/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

ChromeDriver 113.0.5672.63
Google Chrome 113.0.5672.92

I tried downgrading too and that doesn't work

Running with Python 3.9 Ubuntu WSL as root user (I tried non-root but I can't install all the things I need)

Comment: Does it need to run under WSL?

Comment: Yes, Im working withing a framework that uses linux

Answer (score 0):

I was on WSL 1, upgrading to WSL 2 solved it